# didUpdateToLocation not called in iOS GPS Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

I am trying to build a library for GPS in iOS using XCODE, But it is not working as a library, `didUpdateToLocation` is not called when I used in client application, but it is working fine as a application programm. I am not getting where I have done a mistake.

This is my application side code, where I have imported library code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   LocLibrary *mFunctions = [[LocLibrary alloc] init];//Creating a object
   [mFunctions startGps];// Calling library method 
 }
```

Below is my LocLibrary.h

```
@interface LocLibrary : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
CLLocationManager *locMgr;
int latitude,longitude;
}

-(void)startGps;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locMgr;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;
@end
```

Below is LocLibarry.m code, `didUpdateLocation` method is not working

```
 -(void)startGps
  {
  NSLog(@"getGps");
  locMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"getGps1");
  locMgr.delegate = self;
  locMgr.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  locMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
  [locMgr startUpdatingLocation];//Upto this working, it is not calling below code
  }

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { //This method not working
     self.currentLocation = newLocation;
     NSLog(@"Success");
     if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f)
     { 
      [locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];
      NSLog(@"Stopped");
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below line in `viewDidLoad` method you are creating object Of `LocLibrary2` and assigning it to `LocLibrary`.

```
   LocLibrary *mFunctions = [[LocLibrary2 alloc] init];//Creating a object
```

Comment: sorry it is LocLibrary only, i did mistake in pasting it here